# Remove links that appear on the login page of OpenERP (Odoo)

Tags: openerp, odoo

I have installed OpenERP (Odoo) on a system, I want to remove the links for

- Login with OpenERP
- Manage Databases
- Powered by OpenERP

That appear on the login page of OpenERP. I am using OpenERP Odoo v8 Saas-4.

Answer (score 2):

Below is process for removing these links.

1. "Login with OpenERP"

   - Go to Setting->User menu->Oauth Provider
   - Uncheck "Allowed" for OpenERP.com Accounts
2. Removing "Manage Databases" and "Powered by OpenERP"

   - Go to openerp/web module
   - Go to web/view/webclient_templates.xml and make it invisible using html tag  (-->). Line number 64.
   - Do not forgot to upgrade web module after making changes in webclient_templates.xml

```html
<!--          
<a class="oe_login_manage_db" t-attf-href="/web/database/manager{{ '?debug' if debug else '' }}">Manage Databases</a> 
<span class="oe_footer_seperator"> | </span>
     </t>
<a href="http://www.openerp.com" target="_blank">Powered by <span>OpenERP</span></a>
-->
```

Comment: It's probably possible to do it like this but it's not so great to change parts of Odoo core. It would be better to override the module.

Comment: @KasperSouren how to override the module easily?

Answer (score 2):

You have to create a new module with a view to inherit from `web.login_layout` template from `web/views/webclient_templates.xml`. More details in [this question from Odoo Q&A](https://www.odoo.com/forum/help-1/question/how-we-removing-link-that-appear-on-login-page-of-openerp-odoo-54623):

Answer (score 1):

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<templates id="template" xml:space="preserve">
  <t t-extend="Login">
    <t t-jquery="div.oe_login_footer" t-operation="replace">
      <a href="http://www.openerp.com" target="_blank">Powered by <span>OpenERP</span></a>
    </t>
  </t>
</templates>
```

This code is saved in your own module in static>src>xml> in `base.xml` file.
declare in manifest file `openerp.py`